# How to build php70-xdebug from master via Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I've `php70-xdebug` package and I did the following steps:

1. Edited formula by `brew edit php70-xdebug`
2. Then replaced the following line:

   ```
   url "https://pecl.php.net/get/xdebug-2.5.5.tgz"
   ```

   with:

   ```
   url "https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/archive/master.zip"
   ```
3. Run reinstall by: `brew reinstall php70-xdebug --build-from-source`

However it fails with:

```
Error: invalid attribute for formula 'homebrew/php/php70-xdebug': version (nil)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:252:in `validate_attributes!'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:199:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-php/Abstract/abstract-php-extension.rb:20:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:88:in `new'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:88:in `get_formula'
```

I've seen that there is a reference to `build.head` in the following line:

```
Dir.chdir "xdebug-#{version}" unless build.head?
```

which suggest it's possible to build with HEAD, but I'm not sure how.

What would be a proper way of reinstalling `php70-xdebug` from the source using the latest HEAD?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of installing the package from the HEAD, is to add `--HEAD` parameter, e.g.

```
brew reinstall php70-xdebug --build-from-source --HEAD
```

> If `--HEAD` or `--devel` is passed, fetch that version instead of the stable version.

See: `man brew`.

---

> Error: invalid attribute for formula 'homebrew/...': version (nil)

indicates the missing `version` which should be added like:

```
version "2.6.0-dev"
```

right after `url` line (see [example](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/commit/f46d426e641a7fcb04a797a94ec86b65e76ef9d8) here).

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/php70-xdebug.rb does not specify a version … is that even valid?

Comment: @slhck I believe `version` is automatically fetched based on the provided `url`, when I changed the `url` without having version in it, Homebrew started to complain about the missing version.