# Homebrew blocked by Error: invalid attribute for formula 'homebrew/php/php70': version (nil)

Tags: macos, php, homebrew

I've tried `brew update` and `brew doctor`, fixing all errors that have come up thus far, but I'm still getting this error anytime I try to update or remove php70:

`` Error: invalid attribute for formula 'homebrew/php/php70': version (nil)
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:252:in `validate_attributes!'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:199:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:88:in `new'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:88:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:275:in `factory'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:69:in `block in resolved_formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:54:in `map'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:54:in `resolved_formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/reinstall.rb:13:in `reinstall'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:95:in `<main>' ``

I've even tried rebuild as specified here ([How to build php70-xdebug from master via Homebrew?](https://superuser.com/questions/1236668/how-to-build-php70-xdebug-from-master-via-homebrew)) but it returns the same error. Does anyone know how to proceed beyond this?